# Excel VBA break For...Next cycle

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA. I'm trying to find a project ID (A3) if I select a different row (B8).

[image: VBA For]

If the selected row's "A" column's length is 0, go above one cell and repeat until it finds the ID (or currently, anything that length is different than 0). However, my logic fails, because it doesn't work, the for cycle doesn't finish if it found something. What am I missing?

Thanks,

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim SelectedData As Range, count As Long, ProjectID As String
    Set SelectedData = Selection
    count = SelectedData.count
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    Dim FilePath    As String, i As Long
    Dim Filename As String
    ProjectID = SelectedData.EntireRow.Cells(1, "A").Text
    
    If Len(ProjectID) = 0 Then
        
        For i = 0 To -5 Step -1
        ProjectID = SelectedData.EntireRow.Cells(i, "A").Text
        Next
    Else
    MsgBox "ID found"
    End If
    
    'MsgBox Filename
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You code does check `ProjectID` before the loop, but never after. You should test `ProjectID` inside the For loop and exit if if required. Btw, how about using [Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) instead of EntireRow and out of the bound indexes? `ProjectID = SelectedData.Offset(i,-1).Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the cell left of selection has some value. If not jump up `.End(xlUp)` to the next data entry.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    
    Debug.Print GetProjectID(Selection)
    
End Sub


Public Function GetProjectID(ByVal SelectedData As Range) As String
    Dim RetVal As String
    
    If SelectedData.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value <> vbNullString Then
        RetVal = SelectedData.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value
    Else
        RetVal = SelectedData.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).End(xlUp).Value
    End If

    GetProjectID = RetVal
End Function
```

This function expects that some cell in column B is selected when you run it.

---

If you want to be able to select any column change it to:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    
    Debug.Print GetProjectID(Selection)
    
End Sub


Public Function GetProjectID(ByVal SelectedData As Range) As String
    Dim RetVal As String

    Dim CellInColumnA As Range
    Set CellInColumnA = SelectedData.Parent.Cells(SelectedData.Row, 1)

    If CellInColumnA.Value <> vbNullString Then
        RetVal = CellInColumnA.Value
    Else
        RetVal = CellInColumnA.End(xlUp).Value
    End If

    GetProjectID = RetVal
End Function
```

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: @PEH Would you modify this code, so it should work not only if column B is selected but any column and even if multiple cells are selected? Thanks!